# Unable to find the cause of crash-Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, crash, autofill

I would be so appreciated if anybody could spend their time to help me!!!

**What I am facing now**
I was trying to present an view controller from extension and the app crashed without leading me the line of error code.

**What I tried:**
I Added many breakpoints, found that if I don't present the table view controller to show the correct info, no crash. But after the presentation, after the info is loaded rightly in the table, seconds later, crash happens.

**What I can provide:**
I can provide the full crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 03B53A6D-E069-4C4B-98C0-CB61C8C1A688
CrashReporter Key:   1dd64f8867f0eda63dfc5248be178fbebdd71653
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,2
Process:             EverykeyAutofillExtension [98811]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/63F02B78-71D9-405B-AC3F-314868CA262D/Privacy.app/PlugIns/PrivacyExtension.appex/EverykeyAutofillExtension
Identifier:          comPrivacy.ios.PrivacyAutofillExtension
Version:             12 (2.4.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.Privacy.ios.PrivacyAutofillExtension [24965]


Date/Time:           2020-08-26 14:20:40.7959 -0400
Launch Time:         2020-08-26 14:20:03.4675 -0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.5.1 (17F80)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    7.60.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000019819e9d0
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [98811]
Triggered by Thread:  1

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                 0x19853d794 __exceptionPreprocess + 224
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x19825fbcc objc_exception_throw + 55
2   Foundation                     0x198a151fc _AssertAutolayoutOnAllowedThreadsOnly + 419
3   Foundation                     0x19882207c -[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding] + 67
4   Foundation                     0x198821f98 -[NSISEngine optimize] + 111
5   Foundation                     0x198821c0c -[NSISEngine performPendingChangeNotifications] + 111
6   UIKitCore                      0x19ca97e88 -[UIView+ 15605384 (CALayerDelegate) _wantsReapplicationOfAutoLayoutWithLayoutDirtyOnEntry:] + 171
7   UIKitCore                      0x19ca988c4 -[UIView+ 15608004 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2247
8   QuartzCore                     0x19f02b724 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 283
9   QuartzCore                     0x19f03187c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1407100 (CA::Transaction*) + 467
10  QuartzCore                     0x19f03c3c0 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed+ 1450944 (CA::Transaction*) + 139
11  QuartzCore                     0x19ef84f1c CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 700188 (CA::Transaction*, double) + 295
12  QuartzCore                     0x19efae8bc CA::Transaction::commit+ 870588 () + 675
13  QuartzCore                     0x19efaf85c CA::Transaction::release_thread+ 874588 (void*) + 227
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x198256f8c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 579
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x198253df4 _pthread_exit + 79
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x198254e64 _pthread_wqthread_exit + 95
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x198254c04 _pthread_wqthread + 415
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x198257740 start_wqthread + 7


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000198311198 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019831060c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001984bb468 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 148
3   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001984b649c __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
4   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001984b5ce8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   GraphicsServices               0x00000001a260038c GSEventRunModal + 160
6   UIKitCore                      0x000000019c5e4444 UIApplicationMain + 1932
7   libxpc.dylib                   0x00000001981218fc _xpc_objc_main.cold.3 + 208
8   libxpc.dylib                   0x000000019810d4f0 _xpc_objc_main + 212
9   libxpc.dylib                   0x000000019810fb4c xpc_main + 148
10  Foundation                     0x0000000198834534 +[NSXPCListener serviceListener] + 0
11  PlugInKit                      0x00000001a599fd50 0x1a5989000 + 93520
12  PlugInKit                      0x00000001a599fa68 0x1a5989000 + 92776
13  PlugInKit                      0x00000001a59a015c 0x1a5989000 + 94556
14  Foundation                     0x0000000198a0d2c0 NSExtensionMain + 64
15  libdyld.dylib                  0x000000019833d8f0 start + 4

Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_c.dylib              0x000000019819e9d0 __abort + 144
1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x000000019819e9d0 __abort + 144
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x000000019819e940 __abort + 0
3   libc++abi.dylib                0x0000000198306cc0 __cxxabiv1::__aligned_malloc_with_fallback+ 76992 (unsigned long) + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                0x00000001982f8e10 demangling_unexpected_handler+ 19984 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019825fe80 _objc_terminate+ 24192 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                0x000000019830614c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 74060 ()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                0x0000000198308bd8 __cxa_get_exception_ptr + 0
8   libc++abi.dylib                0x0000000198308b98 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func+ 84888 (_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
9   libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019825fcf8 _objc_exception_destructor+ 23800 (void*) + 0
10  Foundation                     0x0000000198a151fc -[NSISEngine tryToOptimizeReturningMutuallyExclusiveConstraints] + 0
11  Foundation                     0x000000019882207c -[NSISEngine _optimizeWithoutRebuilding] + 68
12  Foundation                     0x0000000198821f98 -[NSISEngine optimize] + 112
13  Foundation                     0x0000000198821c0c -[NSISEngine performPendingChangeNotifications] + 112
14  UIKitCore                      0x000000019ca97e88 -[UIView+ 15605384 (CALayerDelegate) _wantsReapplicationOfAutoLayoutWithLayoutDirtyOnEntry:] + 172
15  UIKitCore                      0x000000019ca988c4 -[UIView+ 15608004 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2248
16  QuartzCore                     0x000000019f02b724 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 284
17  QuartzCore                     0x000000019f03187c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1407100 (CA::Transaction*) + 468
18  QuartzCore                     0x000000019f03c3c0 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed+ 1450944 (CA::Transaction*) + 140
19  QuartzCore                     0x000000019ef84f1c CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 700188 (CA::Transaction*, double) + 296
20  QuartzCore                     0x000000019efae8bc CA::Transaction::commit+ 870588 () + 676
21  QuartzCore                     0x000000019efaf85c CA::Transaction::release_thread+ 874588 (void*) + 228
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000198256f8c _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 580
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000198253df4 _pthread_exit + 80
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000198254e64 _pthread_wqthread_legacy_worker_wrap + 0
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000198254c04 _pthread_wqthread + 416
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000198257740 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000198311198 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019831060c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001984bb468 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 148
3   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001984b649c __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
4   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001984b5ce8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   Foundation                     0x00000001987f901c -[NSRunLoop+ 32796 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228
6   Foundation                     0x00000001987f8efc -[NSRunLoop+ 32508 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88
7   UIKitCore                      0x000000019c6875dc -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 152
8   Foundation                     0x0000000198927e20 __NSThread__start__ + 848
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000198253d98 _pthread_start + 156
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000019825774c thread_start + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000198257738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x0000000198311198 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x000000019831060c mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001984bb468 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 148
3   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001984b649c __CFRunLoopRun + 1160
4   CoreFoundation                 0x00000001984b5ce8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
5   CFNetwork                      0x000000019b776894 0x19b775000 + 6292
6   Foundation                     0x0000000198927e20 __NSThread__start__ + 848
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000198253d98 _pthread_start + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000019825774c thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000198257738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000198257738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000198257738 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 1 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000001
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x00000000ffffffe7   x9: 0x00000001e565b228  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x00000001d388d080  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000007
   x16: 0x0000000000000030  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000000016fa62b58
   x20: 0x00000001e2581810  x21: 0x000000016fa62c10  x22: 0x0000000281b4ce40  x23: 0x00000001d3b33000
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x0000000000000068  x26: 0x000000000000009c  x27: 0x0000000000000068
   x28: 0x000000002b310019   fp: 0x000000016fa62b70   lr: 0x000000019819e9d0
    sp: 0x000000016fa62b40   pc: 0x000000019819e9d0 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0xf2000001  Address size fault
```

Comment: It's very difficult to help debug without a Minimum Reproducible Example. But since the code is triggered by `-[NSISEngine tryToOptimizeReturningMutuallyExclusiveConstraints]`, I would look at your auto layout constraints.

Comment: @Howlium  I think I didn't present my VC from main thread, this could be the main reason for occurrences this problem. For now, so far so good. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Look, Your app crashed at:

```
Triggered by Thread:  1
```

and use

```
[CALayer layoutSublayers]
```

looks like, You're updating UI not in main thread somewhere

Comment: Yes, after using DispatchQueue.main.async to present a VC, the crash stop happening (after try 10 times, nothing happened) I think your idea is the solution to me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see something like this

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x19825fbcc objc_exception_throw + 55
```

You should go to the breakpoints tab in Xcode, click the + button, then Exception Breakpoint...

This will create a breakpoint called "All Objective-C exceptions". This will pause the debugger at the moment the exception is thrown, letting you see the exact misuse of Apple's API that is causing the exception.

Comment: ya, after added an Exception Breakpoint, I got "Exception: "Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread."" After I present the current VC inside the main thread, the problem should not happen.